# how to get fixed size drop down(irrespective of text size) in java fx via scene builder tool?

Tags: javafx, scenebuilder

I'm using `ChoiceBox` where there are several drop down items available. Size of the drop down displayed varies depending on the items size. But I want the drop down to be of fixed size irrespective of the size of the items in the drop down. Any ideas on how to implement in Scene builder ?

Answer (score 0):

You could add a CSS stylesheet to set restrictions for the size of the `ListView` used to display the items.

**CSS stylesheet**

```css
.combo-box .combo-box-popup .list-view { /* perhaps use a different/additional class for the combobox to be styled this way??? */
    -fx-min-height: 400;
    -fx-max-height: 400;
}
```

Comment: It's not working. I just placed above sinppet in stylesheet & it's not applied to any choice box items.